# Saving state and column sort in DataTable. (using a cookie)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to make sure state of a [DataTable](http://datatables.net/) is saved in a cookie so when page is reloaded it maintains the sort order of fields.  This is my code, but bStateSave seems to be having no effect whatsoever.

I followed the method described here: http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/state_save.html.

What am I doing wrong?  Will appreciate help!

```
tbl = $(selector).dataTable({
           "bStateSave": true,
           "bProcessing": true,
           "bServerSide": true,
           "sAjaxSource": dataSource,
           "iDeferLoading": totalRecCount,

           "sDom": layout ? layout : defaultLayout,
                   "fnDrawCallback": drawCallback,
                   "aoColumns": aoColumns,
                   "oLanguage": {
                   "sSearch": ""
           }
       });
```

Comment: Try removing as many of the other settings as you can, then re-add them one by one.

Comment: The cookie is named using the tableId + the URL. Can you use chrome dev tools > resources > cookies > to check what cookies are being created?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I found the answer here: http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/41588

In short it will not work when using iDeferLoading.  Will have to maintain that state manually using a cookie which gets created and updated everytime the user sorts or store it elsewhere in the user model.

Comment: Add `,"bStateSave": true` in Datatable property. That's it!